# Installing python-crfsuite fails with [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, crf

I tried to install

```
$ pip install python-crfsuite

Collecting python-crfsuite
Using cached python-crfsuite-0.8.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-crfsuite
Running setup.py install for python-crfsuite
Complete output from command c:\users\vlats\appdata\local\programs    \python    \python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\Users\Vlats\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k0g40k7c\python-crfsuite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record     C:\Users\Vlats\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6zahugn5-record\install-    record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite_dumpparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite_logparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\pycrfsuite
running build_ext
building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

---

> Command "c:\users\vlats\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\Users\Vlats\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k0g40k7c\python-crfsuite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Vlats\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6zahugn5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
>   failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Vlats\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-k0g40k7c\python-crfsuite

Any ideas on what is causing the *error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified* and the subsequent failure of the compile step with error 1?

What are my options to fix it? Or is using `pip install` not the correct way of installing python-crfsuite?

Answer (score 0):

Probably far too late, but for anyone else who finds this page here's the solution...

You need this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

I got the same error output you did, but a coworker of mine got the below output. That's how we found the solution.

---

```
python -m pip install python-crfsuite
Collecting python-crfsuite
Using cached python-crfsuite-0.8.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-crfsuite
Running setup.py install for python-crfsuite ... error
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='c:\users\mweinb~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hivnxb\python-crfsuite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mweinb~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-izyeu8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-2.7
creating build\lib.win32-2.7\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite_dumpparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite_logparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pycrfsuite
copying pycrfsuite__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pycrfsuite
running build_ext
building 'pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='c:\users\mweinb~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hivnxb\python-crfsuite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mweinb~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-izyeu8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mweinb~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hivnxb\python-crfsuite\
```