# cvxpy install results in error in pycharm in win 10 machine. How to fix?

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I am trying to install cvxpy package in pycharm environment. But, the installation is not complete. It is raising the following error msg:

> Skipping optional fixer: buffer
>
> Skipping optional fixer: idioms
>
> Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
>
> Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_cvxcore' extension
>
> error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for cvxpy

and, also following msg:

> running build_ext
>
> building 'fastcache._lrucache' extension
>
> error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for fastcache

The environment I have is the following:

Win 10 64bit machine

pycharm version 2018.1.3

pip version 18.0

I have already tried to install package through conventional installation method for pycharm as well as following command:

```
pip install cvxpy
```

For both of these cases, the installation did not happen and it resulted in the aforementioned error msg.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue to install cvxpy?

Comment: Looks like you need additional packages - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054801/installing-python-crfsuite-fails-with-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-fi

Comment: IMHO the best solution is installation from binaries, there are also required packages, it always worked for me: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxpy

Comment: Thank you. Installing through binary helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/befelix/safe_learning/issues/5